# Timestamping variable & static

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

After some research, I have recognized that there is a lot information about this topic. However, I was not able to figure out how to solve my challenge on my own. 
I want to create two kinds of timestamps (DATE & TIME).

1. In Row BF (BF9:BF) should be a variable timestamp which will be automatically updated if anything in the row from A:BE is changed, e.g. If there is a change in any cell in A9:BE9 then cell BF9 should show the date and time of the last update.
2. In Row BG (BG9:BG) should be a static timestamp which shows the date of the first time any data was inserted in column A, e.g if "12345" was inserted in cell A9 on 23.04.2018, then cell BG9 should show 23.04.2018 forever.

Does somebody know how to express this in lines of code? Unfortunately, I haven't figured it out on my own yet.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Thank you for contribution. However, I don't know it and I therefor ask for help to learn and understand how to do it on my own

Comment: This will help you the next time you ask for help, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this we can use the `Worksheet_change` Event. First we'll test if the `Target` change is in the defined range that we want to monitor and if it is we will insert a timestamp into the 'Change Timestamp' cell on that row (using the row from the Target). If there hasn't been any changes before, the 'First Change' cell will be blank so we'll test to see if it is blank and if so insert the date.

**Updated after comments:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Seperator As String

    Seperator = ","

    ' Test if change of cell (Target) is in the range specified (A9:BE)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A9:BE" & Me.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":BE" & Target.Row)
            ' Test if row is empty. I've given two examples here
            ' The first one is simpler but won't identify empty formulas
            ' The second one will compare the values in the range and compare it against a string that would be produced if all the cells were vbNullString
            ' The Join function will only take a 1D array - setting it just to the range will create a 2D array and produce an error so we double transpose
            ' (you could index instead if you want) to get a 1D array

            'If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count = .Cells.Count Then
            If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value2)), Seperator) = String(.Cells.Count - 1, Seperator) Then
                Me.Range("BF" & Target.Row).ClearContents
                Me.Range("BG" & Target.Row).ClearContents
            Else
                ' If it is insert timestamp in cell BF using row from Target (Cell that was changed)
                Me.Range("BF" & Target.Row).Value2 = Now()
                ' Test if cell BG has anything in it. If not insert date (replicating first change behaviour)
                If Me.Range("BG" & Target.Row).Value2 = vbNullString Then
                    ' Insert date into cell BG using row from Target
                    Me.Range("BG" & Target.Row).Value2 = Date
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. As mentioned in the question, I do have my problems with this code for timestamps. Could you therefor be so kind and walk me through your code? :) I really try to understand it, so I can code it on my own next time.

Comment: thank you very much for your support :) The code works smooth and I made some edits to get a different format `Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy  hh:mm:ss")` and `Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")` . In a second step I tried to apply a further condition. There should only be a timestamp in BF & BG if there is any data in  `Range ("A:BE")` --> If there is no data in any of those cells there should be no timestemp either or in case the data is deleted the timestamp should be deleted as well. I tried it by adding an additional if-function but this seems not to work. Do you probably have a hint for me?

Comment: Personally I'd just format the entire column manually to get the desired format. Also, have a look at my update

Comment: Okay I used the `.ClearContents`-Function as well but I've to admit I would've never figured out the if-function you are using! Thank @Tom for your amazing support! :)